# Styling table rows with alternating background colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a dynamic table in my iOS application. For differentiating between rows I use different colour for rows. e.g for even rows darker blue and for odd rows lighter blue. It is all working perfectly and no issues at all. The content is very dynamic and handling all the cases is making the code very messy and difficult to maintain. I want to clean up the code and so searching for the best solution.

**What I have done:**
I have created a generic class that has two methods to return UILabel with all the properties already set. (one method returning the lighter blue label and other darker blue). I call these method inside cellForRowAtIndexPath based on the fact that index is odd or even I call the respective method.

I am not sure if this is a correct approach. Can I any one guide me if there is a better approach.

Comment: The way to check odd/even indexpath.row is best approach for you.

Comment: If you are not getting any cell resuse issues, like wrong labels appearing in wrong rows, you seem to be good

Comment: This is just style preference.  You could create two separate cell prototypes with separate cell reuse identifiers: @"reuseIdentifer0" and @"reuseIdentifier1".  You could always dequeue using the identifier [NSString stringWithFormat:@"reuseIdentifier%@",indexPath.row%2].  But just changing the color of the UILabels might not warrant a separate prototype cell - although it just might be nice to see the cells in storyboard though.

Answer (score 0):

write this code inside Your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
if(indexPath.row%2 == 0)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor YourColor];
else
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor YourColor];
```